# How to raise PropertyChangedEventHandler when a sub property is changed in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a property called *PriceChangeInPercentWeekly* which has other properties like *LastOpenPrice*, *LastClosePrice*, etc.

I am changing these continuously. But how can I raise PropertyChangedEventHandler for *PriceChangeInPercentWeekly* when a sub-property is changed?

When *PriceChangeInPercentWeekly* itself is changed, I raised it using my custom SetField function. But how can I do this for sub-properties. Because sub-properties do not know the instanced class, right?

```
PriceChange priceChangeInPercentWeekly;
public PriceChange PriceChangeInPercentWeekly
{
    get => this.priceChangeInPercentWeekly;
    set => SetField ( ref this.priceChangeInPercentWeekly, value,
        "PriceChangeInPercentWeekly"
        );
}
```

Comment: It is the job of whatever view is using the 'PriceChange' view model to register appropirate events to do...whatever it is supposed to be doing. Just to be sure: You are following the MVVM pattern, right?

Comment: Yes, but so you are saying I should have a "changed event" inside PriceChange class and then subscribe to it for every instance, which will raise the appropriate property changed at that level that will trigger an update in the WPF bound UI?

Comment: If the view or the viewmodel containing "PriceChangeViewModel" instances needs to do something in response to a property changing, it has to register a event for it. However it is not quite sure what it is supposed ot be doing. Or why. Could you specify what you are trying to do when the property changes?

Comment: Actually I am not doing anything special, I just have my datagrid control bound to some of the properties in the PriceChange instance which is inside an item stored in ObservableCollection. So one of the colums will show PriceChange.Value, and use PriceChange.Color for text color, etc. So everytime the properties inside PriceChange instance changes, I need to notify WPF so it can refresh. Otherwise nothing updates in the UI.

Comment: That explanation should be in the Post itself. And honestly, it sounds like you have a not working binding or change nofication. The best answer I can give you, is the one about 3 kinds of bindings you need for lists.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you have a issue with properly binding in a collection case. When dealing with collections in MVVM, there are actually 3 seperate kinds of bindings/Change Notifications you need. If any one is missing, you end up getting issues with non-updates pretty quickly:

1. Whatever class is holding `LastOpenPrice`, `LastClosePrice`, `PriceChange` and the like - it needs change notificaiton on each and every property. Whatever template you use to display that class, needs to properly bind to each of those properties.
2. You need change notificaiton if anything is added or removed from the Collection. That is the *only* change notification `ObservableCollection<ClassThatHoldsThosePrices>` takes care off.
3. Whatever property exposes the `ObservableList<ClassThatHoldsThosePrices>` or its Collection View needs change notificaiton as well. ObservableCollections do not support bulk additions. With a big changes you usually have to build a new list in the background, then replace the whole collection.

At this point it usually becomes a question of properly setting up (or automatically having set up) the 3 kinds of bindings. The proper MVVM pattern is not a easy thing to learn and it can not tell if you did it properly, so it is hard to say where the issues could be. About 8 years ago I wrote a short introducing which I think should still be okay-ish for learning the basics: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: Thanks, I have already 2 and 3. And also 1 for primitive properties like decimal bool color, etc that exist on T of ObservableList<T>. So I have T.Price, that already raises "Price" change anytime it's changed. What I am wondering is how to raise "MyPriceChange" on PriceChange.LastOpenPrice is changed, etc. Because PriceChange is a generic class used in multiple places. Right now I have T.LastOpenPrice and therefore I am tracking "LastOpenPrice" change.

Comment: @JoanVenge I am realy confused why It is `T.PriceChange.LastOpenPrice` and not `T.LastOpenPrice`. Also you realy need to give use your name for those classes. Talking just about a property is confusing. And it is not like they can exist without the class containing them.

Comment: Because I have many different price changes for minute, day, hour, month, week, year, so it creates so many properties to keep track of that's why I am trying to generalize it like this. It becomes a lot of work if I want to add a new price change for example rather than just instancing another PriceChange and then setting the right properties under it (using a rest API).

Comment: @JoanVenge One ViewModel holding/exposing another ViewModel is in no way special. Usually you got a chain of ViewModels, starting all the way at the Application ViewModel - then one that is propably instantiated in the App.xaml, because all the Windows would need access to it.